# How do I extract last element between angle brackets using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

How do I extract last element between angle brackets using regular expressions? The last element is the currency, I only need `GBP` or `USD`.

```
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Dec 28 11:20:00 UTC 2015>-<Mon Dec 28 18:05:00 UTC 2015>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBR>-<ROUND>-<GBP>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NONE>-<ONEWAY>-<GBP>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NONE>-<ROUND>-<USD>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NSNS>-<ROUND>-<GBP>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ONEWAY>-<GBP>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ROUND>-<GBP>
<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ROUND>-<USD>
```

I have tried `/&\<[A-Z]+\>(?=$)/` and `/\<[A-Za-z]+\>$/` but it's not working.

Comment: [`<([^>]*?)>\n`](https://regex101.com/r/yH2rL0/2)

Comment: [Your `<[A-Za-z]+>$` regex is working](https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/1).

Comment: @Tushar make that into an answer, you were the first.

Comment: @stribizhev it's not working for me for some reason.

Comment: @Ciprian I think you didn't use `gm` flags

Comment: @Tushar ah, multiline! You are correct. I was using http://regexr.com/ and default is `/g`.

Comment: @Ciprian: If you post no code, it won't work, sure. You should check the regex in the real code. I doubt you have a multiline string.

Comment: [Check this](https://eval.in/457636)

Comment: @Ciprian: Tushar's suggested regex does not cover the case when it is at the end of the string. **Your 2nd regex is the correct one**. I suggest removing this post. Just if you have a multiline string, add `/m`: `/<[A-Za-z]+>$/m`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<[^>]*>\s*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vP2zF2/4

```
$re = "/<[^>]*>\\s*$/m"; 
$str = "<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Dec 28 11:20:00 UTC 2015>-<Mon Dec 28 18:05:00 UTC 2015>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBR>-<ROUND>-<GBP>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NONE>-<ONEWAY>-<GBP>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NONE>-<ROUND>-<USD>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<NSNS>-<ROUND>-<GBP>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ONEWAY>-<GBP>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ROUND>-<GBP>\n<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Jan 04 11:20:00 UTC 2016>-<Mon Jan 04 18:05:00 UTC 2016>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBC>-<ROUND>-<USD>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used my own expression (without escaped characters) and used it like this:

```
$str = "<ABZ>-<BOS>-<Mon Dec 28 11:20:00 UTC 2015>-<Mon Dec 28 18:05:00 UTC 2015>-<EI>-<3241>-<EI>-<139>-<USBR>-<ROUND>-<GBP>";

preg_match("/<[A-Za-z]+>$/", $str, $match);
$match = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('', ''), $match[0]);
$currency = $match;

echo $currency;
```

I didn't need `/gm` as it's not multiline, it's a CSV extracted line by line.